# Terraform Azure SQL server admin password change forces recreating of resource

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, terraform, azure-synapse

I have the following piece of Terraform code where Terraform fetches the sql admin password from a key vault. When I changed the administrator login and passsword in the key vault and then run terraform again to update the sql server, it destroys the sql database and sql server.

Is this standard procedure or can I change this behavior? One could understand that recreating the resources is not really feasible in a production environment. I know a lifecycle hook could prevent the deletion of a resource, but such a thing would then break the pipeline if I am correct.

```
data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "sql_admin_user_secret" {
  name         = var.sql_admin_user_secret_name
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "sql_admin_password_secret" {
  name         = var.sql_admin_password_secret_name
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id
}

resource "azurerm_sql_server" "sql_server" {
  name                         = var.sql_server_name
  resource_group_name          = var.resource_group_name
  location                     = var.location
  version                      = var.sql_server_version
  administrator_login          = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.sql_admin_user_secret.value
  administrator_login_password = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.sql_admin_password_secret.value
}

resource "azurerm_sql_database" "sql_database" {
  name                             = var.sql_database_name
  resource_group_name              = var.resource_group_name
  location                         = var.location
  server_name                      = azurerm_sql_server.sql_server.name
  edition                          = var.sql_edition
  requested_service_objective_name = var.sql_service_level
}
```

I could add something like this, but this only prevents a destroy and ignores changes in those fields respectively. Which is again, not really an option.

```
lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
    ignore_changes = ["administrator_login", "administrator_login_password"]
}
```

**Update:**

The way of working is to never update the `administrator_login`. `administrator_login_password` can be updated separately, which doesn't cause the instance to be recreated.

Comment: Can you share the plan output as well please? https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/1db85f83e8e60f72050949766191f8400842d2e0/azurerm/internal/services/sql/sql_server_resource.go#L68-L72 doesn't have a `ForceNew` on the `administrator_login_password` parameter so this shouldn't happen purely from the password being updated.

Comment: I think I now understand the issue better. The administrator_login as well as the administrator_login_password were both updated, so that it needed to recreate the resource. Updating the password alone did not force the resource to be recreated. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Nebulastic, please mark the answer if you think it's helpful.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [official doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/sql_server#administrator_login), if you change the `administrator_login`, it is expected the resource to be recreated. However, if you only change `administrator_login_password`, it should get updated.

> administrator_login - (Required) The administrator login name for the new server. Changing this forces a new resource to be created.

There is nothing much can be done here since Terraform is communicating with the Azure API, which is not designed to update the administrator user id of Azure SQL without creating a new resource.